# terra R coord.ref unnamed

Tags: r, r-raster, terra

I am using the `terra` library with harmonized HLS data (https://hls.gsfc.nasa.gov/). These are HDF4_EOS files (you can download an image here: https://hls.gsfc.nasa.gov/data/v1.4/S30/2020/11/T/M/M/).

Once downloading a scene and attempting to load in R with the sds function, (i.e., `datat=sds(ImageIn)`) it works but the `coord.ref` is unnamed, as shown below:

```
    datat 
    class       : SpatRasterDataset 
    subdatasets : 14 
    dimensions  : 3660, 3660 (nrow, ncol)
    nlyr        : 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 
    resolution  : 30, 30  (x, y)
    extent      : 399960, 509760, 5090220, 5200020  (xmin, xmax, ymin, 
                  ymax)
    coord. ref. : unnamed 
    source(s)   : HLS.S30.T11TMM.2019310.v1.4.hdf 
    names       : B01, B02, B03, B04, B05, B06, B07, B08, B8A, B09, B10, 
                  B11, B12, QA
```

When I use `terra::crs(ImageIn)`, I get the following error message:

> Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  :
> unable to find an inherited method for function ‘crs’ for signature
> ‘"character"’

If I use the function `get_subdatasets()` from the `gdalUtils` library and the function `raster()` from the `raster` library (i.e. `raster(imageIn[2])`) the crs is found (i.e. `+proj=utm +zone=11 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs`).

```
     class      : RasterLayer 
     dimensions : 3660, 3660, 13395600  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
     resolution : 30, 30  (x, y)
     extent     : 399960, 509760, 5090220, 5200020  (xmin, xmax, ymin, 
                  ymax)
      crs        : +proj=utm +zone=11 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs 
      source     : HLS.S30.T11TMM.2019310.v1.4.hdf:Grid:B02 
      names      : HLS.S30.T11TMM.2019310.v1.4.hdf.Grid.B02 
      values     : -32768, 32767  (min, max)
```

Is there a way to get the `terra` library to find the projection of the raster?

Thanks!!

Comment: Did you try `terra::crs(imageIn[2])` ?

Comment: can you please provide an example file, and can you edit your question and `show` the results you get with terra and raster?

Comment: Thank you both for the suggestions. I have edited by question above.

Answer (score 0):

That was not intended and this has been fixed.

```
library(terra)
r <- rast("HLS.S30.T11TMM.2020002.v1.4.hdf")
r
#class       : SpatRaster 
#dimensions  : 3660, 3660, 14  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
#resolution  : 30, 30  (x, y)
#extent      : 399960, 509760, 5090220, 5200020  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#coord. ref. : +proj=utm +zone=11 +ellps=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs 
#sources     : HLS.S30.T11TMM.2020002.v1.4.hdf:Grid:B01  
#              HLS.S30.T11TMM.2020002.v1.4.hdf:Grid:B02  
#              HLS.S30.T11TMM.2020002.v1.4.hdf:Grid:B03  
#              ... and 11 more source(s)
#names       : Grid:B01, Grid:B02, Grid:B03, Grid:B04, Grid:B05, Grid:B06, ...
```

You can also use the `crs` method like below

```
crs(r, proj=TRUE)
#[1] "+proj=utm +zone=11 +ellps=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs"
```

There is no crs method for a SpatRasterDataset (yet), but you can do

```
s <- sds("HLS.S30.T11TMM.2020002.v1.4.hdf")
crs(s[[1]], proj=TRUE)
#[1] "+proj=utm +zone=11 +ellps=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs"
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. It works.